# Search LaTeX text in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, latex

I need to search over **LaTeX** documents in my **MySQL** database. Are there any differences between searching LaTeX (numbers and bunch of symbols like ^,+,-,[],{},...) and 'regular' text?

I have a table where 'body' is **FULLTEXT** and if I make **FULLTEXT MySQL search** on 'body' column

```
SELECT * FROM latex WHERE MATCH(body) AGAINST('$x-[3x-(5+x)]-8')
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM latex WHERE MATCH(body) AGAINST('$x-[3x-(5+x)]-8' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I get **0 results**. Even if I have bunch of rows and only one (tried also with 1,2,3,3+) match these condition. If I use `LIKE` method I get that one result out. If I use **text** (which is in that same document) I get that one result out. Are numbers and symbols problem for **FULLTEXT search**?

Would results be any better with for example, **Sphinx**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that formula snippets would be included in a fulltext index.  A fulltext index is designed for words and will most likely completely ignore something like your formula.

Comment: I'm thinking about replacements for ex. ( _openparenthesis, ) _closeparenthesis, $ _dollar and so on. And then search those words?